# Can I prevent IIS from recycling if /bin changes?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, asp.net, iis-7.5

IIS recycles an ASP.net Application Pool automatically whenever either the /bin folder or the web.config file changes.

Is there a way to disable that feature? This is IIS 7.5 running in Integrated mode, and the underlying intention is to allow applications (with Full Trust) to update and restart themselves.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can.

In the Application Pool > Advanced Settings > Recycling section, set the Disable Recyling for Configuation Changes to True.

Comment: Even with the Disable Recycling for Configuration Changes = True, we could not prevent IIS from soft recycling the associated apppool when any file was added or removed from bin - even a text file.